# Retrieving cookie from a Container in ASP.NET MVC and C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

```
//Controller code
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
//makes new cookie here
cookieContainer.Add(myCookie);


//Service/Facade code
//myCookie gets passed here
```

How do I pull the cookie out of the container to make sure it's the right cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you trying to use cookies with web services, check out this Microsoft Support article:

[HOW TO: Use CookieContainer to Maintain a State in Web Services When You Use Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816637)